# Is there an alternative for the :checked function javascript radio buttons for normal buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, checked

I have recently come across the :checked function in javascript for radio buttons and I really wanted to use it with normal buttons. Is there any alternatives that I can use to mimic the effect of the :checked function. I have heard of using hidden states before. Basically, I want to retrieve the value of the button when clicked and only the button that I clicked value has to be received. Could anyone give some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Use a hidden field, and update that with javascript. Retrieve the value from the hidden field.

Comment: `Basically, I want to retrieve the value of the button when clicked and only the button that I clicked value has to be received.` - Can't you just use a click handler on a regular old button?

Comment: Yes Squiggs - but I don't know how to do that - could you give me an example

Comment: Sorry, I am just recently learning javascript. What do you mean James, do you mean an onClick handler?

Answer (score 0):

Listen for a click event on the button and then the value is available with `.value`

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").value
```

That said... It's not great UX to use buttons to store a value. The expected process is to use buttons to do something with a group of data. Eg: "save", "submit", "update"

Comment: I am creating a survey style web page using dynamically generated buttons depending on the no. of questions and answers. At the end point I need to retrieve the answer someone gave to a question accessing it by the name attribute and then the value attribute from there. The name attribute is the question number and the value held. It seemed to only work with radio buttons when I used :checked - I need to retrieve the selected answer and append it to an array. How would I access it in this case please?

Comment: instead of a name attribute use an ID. That's much easier to grab in JS `:checked` is only a true/false but its persistent which doesn't exist on a button. You could simply style a checkbox/radio + label to "look like" a button.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can mimic the effect of the **:checked** attribute by adding classes to your buttons upon being clicked, since this is not available in buttons. You can add a class such as "checked" once the button is clicked, and when retrieving the value, just check whether the button contains this class. Just an idea.

Comment: I am creating a survey style web page using dynamically generated buttons depending on the no. of questions and answers. Yes it's a good idea however the feature which I needed to implement the generated buttons with a name and value field. At the end point I need to retrieve the answer someone gave to a question accessing it by the name attribute and then the value attribute from there. The name attribute is the question number and the value held. It seemed to only work with radio buttons when I used :checked - I need to retrieve the selected answer and append it to an array.